# Allow others on network to open workbook on my local PC

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm opening a workbook stored on my local PC (My Documents) from a workbook stored on a network share via a custom VBA UDF.

This works for myself but not for others.

I know it is a privileges issue however my PC is on a domain and I don't have administrative privileges to share the folder on my PC.

Is there a workaround, without having to store the local workbook on the network share?

The VBA function that opens the workbook from the workbook stored on the network share.

```
Public Function INDIRECTVBA(wbPath As String, wsName As String, rng As String) As Variant
' Check if Timesheet.xlsm workbook is open. If not then create new excel instance and open workbook.
    If Not FileInUse(wbPath) Then
        Set excelApp = New Excel.Application: excelApp.Visible = False: Set wb = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(wbPath)
    Else
        Set excelApp = GetObject(wbPath).Application: Set wb = excelApp.Workbooks("Timesheet.xlsm")
    End If
    
    INDIRECTVBA = wb.Worksheets(wsName).Range(rng).Value2

End Function
```

This function is called from a formula.

```
=VALUE(IF(MONTH(TODAY())=SHEET(SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(CELL("Filename",$FZZ$999999),"]",REPT("?",999)),999),"?",""))-1, IF(DAY(TODAY())>E1,  INDIRECTVBA("\\des.grplnk.net\home\christian.coombes\My_Documents\TimeRecording\2020\Timesheet.xlsm",LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(CELL("Filename",$FZZ$999999),"]",REPT("?",999)),999),"?",""),3),"$F"&E1+1), 0), IF(MONTH(TODAY())>SHEET(SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(CELL("Filename",$FZZ$999999),"]",REPT("?",999)),999),"?",""))-1, INDIRECTVBA("\\des.grplnk.net\home\christian.coombes\My_Documents\TimeRecording\2020\Timesheet.xlsm",LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(CELL("Filename",$FZZ$999999),"]",REPT("?",999)),999),"?",""),3),"$F"&E1+1), 0)))-SUM(E3:E4,E31:E39)
```

Comment: Excel will only be able to open files dependant on the permissions of the user under which the process is running. If a colleague is unable to manually navigate to your own My Documents and open a file, then they will also be unable to do so in Excel. You need to either find some way of sharing your folder; or put your own file on a properly-shared network location.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I suspected as much but was just wondering if I had missed something!?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The Excel process has the same network permissions as the user who's running it.

This means that if one of your colleagues is unable to directly navigate to your own My Documents folder and open the file in question, their Excel will also be unable to do so.

You need to either:

1) Find a way to share your own folders to the network, and grant permission to other users, or;

2) Upload your document in question to a common shared network location, and reference it from there.